# Get total size of file in current directory (not include size of subdirectory)

Tags: bash, filesystems, size

I'm a newbie in Linux and English is not my primary language.

- I have folder structure (example):

  ```
    /folder1/file1.zip (1GB)
    /folder1/file2.zip (1GB)
    /folder1/subfolder/file3.zip (1GB)
    /folder1/subfolder/file4.zip (1GB)
  ```
- I tried `tree -dh /folder1` command, got 4K (size) each folder.
- I tried `du -h /folder1` command, got result:

  ```
    2GB     /folder1/subfolder
    4GB     /folder1
  ```
- I need this result:

  ```
    2GB      /folder1/subfolder
    2GB      /folder1
  ```

Please help me which command can do that?

Thanks and best regards.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the GNU implementation of `du` (the one most commonly found in desktop/server distributions of software for Linux), you can use the `-S` / `--separate-dirs` option to *not* include the disk usage of subdirectories and their contents in the total for a given directory (note that the size of the directory file itself is included in its own reported disk usage):

```
$ du -hS folder1
2.0G    folder1/subfolder
2.0G    folder1
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks Freddy.